# window.open does not load relative path file in reactjs . Is it possible to load relative path files?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have tried load realtive path file inside the **window.open()** method but it doesn't loaded. The  **src** folder contains **test.html** file and **test.tsx file**

test.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome test page</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

test.tsx file

```
import React from "react";

export const Test = () => {
  const openWindow = () => {
  const features = 
  "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,
   addressbar=no,width=320,height=480";
  // const url = "./test.html";
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5501/src/test.html";
  window.open(url, "self", features);
    };
 return (
   <>
      <button onClick={openWindow}>Open Window</button>
   </>
  );
};
```

If I tried this way "http://127.0.0.1:5501/src/test.html" it loads correclty and display **test.html** file output.

output is

[image]

If I tried this way "./test.html" it doesn't work it shows **cannot GET /test.html**

output is

[image]

Is there anyother way to load text.html file ? kindly share your suggestions...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there shouldn't be an html file in src, As per my understanding, you need to write HTML inside tsx file and then start the react dev server using `npm run start` Your test.html should be index.html and should be in the public folder. let me know if it works.

Comment: I just moved test.html file to public folder. It works!

Answer (score 0):

The relative path will relate to current browser path, not to the tsx file source.

So, if you your current URL is `http://127.0.0.1:5501/` you can use:

```
window.open('src/test.html')
```